# How to access objective function value in pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to output the objective value from my pyomo model. I did access to the variable values but I cannot get access to the objective function value. My codes are:

```
   instance = model.create_instance(data)

opt = SolverFactory('cplex')
results = opt.solve(instance)
instance.solutions.store_to(results)
results.write()
# instance.display()

# output the solution
var_val = []
for v in instance.component_data_objects(Var):
    var_val.append(int(v.value))

obj_val = value(instance.obj)
```

And the last line gives error info:

```
    obj_val = value(instance.obj)
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

But I can clearly see the value from `result.write()` :

```
 Message: None
  Objective:
    obj:
      Value: 104728.80233047833
  Variable:
    x[0,1]:
      Value: 1569
    x[1,0]:
      Value: 1569
    x[1,1]:
      Value: 206
    x[2,2]:
      Value: 230
    x[2,3]:
      Value: 213
    x[3,2]:
      Value: 213
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you importing Pyomo? If you're using `from pyomo.environ import *` the value function will be included. If you're importing each thing you're using individually then you just need to make sure you import the `value` function: `from pyomo.environ import value`

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to import 'value' from 'pyomo.environ' because I am trying to make the whole model file a user-defined function, where it is required to explicitly state all imported items. Btw, if I want to import everything from pyomo.environ in a function file, where clearly I cannot use `*`, is there another way of importing other than explicitly importing everything I am using?

Comment: You could do something like: `import pyomo.environ as pe` and then pre-pend `pe.` to everything you use from pyomo.environ i.e. `pe.Constraint`, `pe.value`